# PowerShell get running explorer process and their documents

Tags: powershell, popup, document, explorer

How can i access document property of already running explorer processes. i am using following line of code to get process.

$ie2 =  Get-Process |where {$*.mainWindowTItle -eq "Windowtitletext"} | where {$*.ID -ne $ieParentProcessNumber}

now i want to do some processing on this processes like $ie2.Document etc.

Comment: Do you mean "Windows Explorer" or "Internet Explorer"?  I suspect it is the latter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to access the Document (i.e a webpage's data) directly from the process. This is not possible using the get-process.

You would need to create a instance of a IE com object for example or use the System.Net.WebClient if you want to just read data from  a web site. Post more info about what you are trying to do and we can possibly help you out  better

Comment: In Short : I am trying to get document of a popup window. 
Description: I have asp.net page with a hyperlink when i click on that link it calls javascript 
__dopostback event which shows a popup window and on that popup window i have option to download that 
zip file. the problem i am facing right now is that when i call click event in powershell a new iexplorer 
process is started (for popup window) how can i get document of that popup window and click on it.

Comment: Doing this pureley with powershell might be a bit of a pain , rather use something like Watin + Powershell. Or you can try using send keys to the active window to perform what ever operation you want

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the ie window:

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$popup = $app.Windows() | where {$_.LocationName -like "*foo*"}
$popup.document
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you'll receive 1 object:

```
(Get-Process explorer).CPU
```

If you want to know what are the available properties:

```
Get-Process explorer | Get-Member
```

If you have more than one object in your result set (e.g. Get-Process returning mutiple processes mathing search criteria):

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Handles -ge 200 } | Foreach-Object { $_.CPU }
```